# Wordpress: Как правильно вывести конкретную запись внутри цикла вывода других записей?

Tags: wordpress

Есть два типа записей: Спикеры(данные о выступающих) и Выступления (данные о выступлении - тема, время, а также выбор из существующих спикеров).
Вывожу выступления

```
<?php $speech_list = new WP_Query( array( 'speech_zal' => $zal_slug ) ); ?>
 <?php if ($speech_list -> have_posts()): ?>
  <?php while ($speech_list -> have_posts()): $speech_list -> the_post();?>
   --HTML блоки со вставками полей из материала--
  <?php endwhile;?>
 <?php endif;?>
```

Как правильно внутри вывести нужный пост по id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дошел. С помощью функции get_post().